# scrapyd Error on schedule new spider

Tags: scrapy, scrapyd

I cannot schedule a spider run

Deploy seems to be ok:

```
Deploying to project "scraper" in http://localhost:6800/addversion.json
Server response (200):
{"status": "ok", "project": "scraper", "version": "1418909664", "spiders": 3}
```

I scheduling a new spider run :

```
curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=scraper -d spider=spider


{"status": "ok", "jobid": "3f81a0e486bb11e49a6800163ed5ae93"}
```

but on scrapyd I get this error:

```
2014-12-18 14:39:12+0100 [-] Process started:  project='scraper' spider='spider' job='3f81a0e486bb11e49a6800163ed5ae93' pid=28565 log='/usr/scrapyd/logs/scraper/spider/3f81a0e486bb11e49a6800163ed5ae93.log' items='/usr/scrapyd/items/scraper/spider/3f81a0e486bb11e49a6800163ed5ae93.jl'
2014-12-18 14:39:13+0100 [Launcher,28565/stderr] Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
        "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
        exec code in run_globals
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapyd/runner.py", line 39, in <module>
2014-12-18 14:39:13+0100 [Launcher,28565/stderr]     main()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapyd/runner.py", line 36, in main
        execute()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 143, in execute
        _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 89, in _run_print_help
        func(*a, **kw)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 150, in _run_command
        cmd.run(args, opts)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/commands/crawl.py", line 58, in run
        spider = crawler.spiders.create(spname, **opts.spargs)
2014-12-18 14:39:13+0100 [Launcher,28565/stderr]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spidermanager.py", line 48, in create
        return spcls(**spider_kwargs)
      File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/scraper/spiders/spider.py", line 104, in __init__
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
        mkdir(name, mode)
    OSError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/tmp/scraper-1418909944-dKTRZI.egg/logs/'
2014-12-18 14:39:14+0100 [-] Process died: exitstatus=1  project='scraper'
```

Any ideas? :(

Comment: what does this mean:

OSError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/tmp/scraper-1418909944-dKTRZI.egg/logs/'  ?

Comment: Well, it seems that it can't access that location. Maybe there is a problem with access rights?

Comment: drwxrwxrwx   3 root root  4096 Dec 18 16:16 tmp

Comment: it seems taht it cannot create that logs dir on that location, or what?   why?

Comment: The traceback is pointing to line 104 in ``scraper/spiders/spider.py`` -- what is the code in that line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create a directory inside an egg.

`OSError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/tmp/scraper-1418909944-dKTRZI ---->.egg<----- /logs/'`